# Unable to add duplicate entry through informatica

Tags: informatica

I am using Informatica to finally write in the oracle table after performing certain logical operations on the data.
The problem is that if a certain ID was already previously processed and is present in the target table then it is not inserted again.
Please suggest a workaround.

Comment: What error is it throwing?

Comment: Other that duplicate data, rest all are loading?  Are you using update strategy?

Answer (score 0):

Hi,
 This is because you might have same primary key in the source which is available in the target. Look into primary key columns and try loading them.

Altering your target table

```
alter table target_table_name drop constraint constraint name;
```

Comment: Yes, its the primary key issue, my problem is I don't want to remove the primary key from the target table as it is used later in the mapping.
Would changing the advance settings from update as update to update else insert or insert else update make any difference??

Comment: Yes of course you should not remove primary key form the target table

Comment: You are getting same number in the source which you use to map primary key column in the target?

Comment: If you are inserting primary key column and same number is coming in a source then, you cannot duplicate the data in the target. You have only one option for that

Comment: You need to alter target table

Comment: Yes, That is the issue which I wish to overcome

Comment: How to alter table?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124382/discussion-between-jim-macaulay-and-snigdha).